# Передать класс в конструкторе

Tags: c++, sfml

Есть  конструктор `WindowMgmt` как присвоить полю `window` первый аргумент

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#pragma once
using namespace sf;
class WindowMgmt
{
public:
    RenderWindow window;
    WindowMgmt(RenderWindow &windowarg) {
            window = windowarg;
    };
    void closeOnEvent(){
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }

    ~WindowMgmt(void);
};
```

Создаю экземпляр так

```
WindowMgmt win(RenderWindow (VideoMode(200, 200), "Super Mario"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Брать ссылку от временной величины нельзя...

Так не хотите?

```
WindowMgmt(const RenderWindow &windowarg):window(windowarg){};
```

**Update**
Увы, я не знаю, что из себя представляет класс `RenderWindow`. Если он не копируется, то его передавать нельзя - создавайте его прямо в классе:

```
WindowMgmt(...Ваши параметры...)
:window(...Ваши параметры...) {}
```

т.е. вызывайте как

```
WindowMgmt win(VideoMode(200, 200), "Super Mario");
```

Comment: тогда `Ошибка 2 error C2248: sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable: невозможно обратиться к private член, объявленному в классе "sf::NonCopyable" d:\sfml-2.0\include\sfml\graphics\rendertarget.hpp 419 1 Mario`

Comment: Ну, см. обновленное решение. Просто конструктор должен быть с теми же параметрами, что и у `RenderWindow` (смотрите сами, какие)